# Encoding of every characte in Url including - _ . ! ~ * ' ( ) in javascript

Tags: javascript

I used encodeURIComponent() method to encode the url in javascript..by using that method also some characters arent getting encoded..Could anyone suggest a method or code that encodes each and every character in the Url including
 - _ . ! ~ * ' ( ).Thank you.

Comment: [encodeURIComponent](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.3) only encodes the characters that need to be encoded in a URI/URL, it won't encode things that don't need to be encoded. You can use [`charCodeAt`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.5) to encode any characer, but you will likely need to write a custom decoder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own encode and decode functions:

```
function encodeString(s) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i=0, iLen=s.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    result.push('%' + s.charCodeAt(i));
  }
  return result.join('');
}

function decodeString(s) {
  s = s.split('%');
  result = [];

  for (var i=0, iLen=s.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    result.push(String.fromCharCode(s[i]));
  }
  return result.join('');
}

var s = "- _ . ! ~ * ' ( )";

alert(encodeString(s)); // %45%32%95%32%46%32%33%32%126%32%42%32%39%32%40%32%41

alert(decodeString(encodeString(s))); // - _ . ! ~ * ' ( )
```

#### Edit

The above seems to encode in base 10, whereas encodeURIComponent seems to encode in base 16, so here's an alternative that uses base 16 (hex):

```
function encodeString(s) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i=0, iLen=s.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    result.push('%' + s.charCodeAt(i).toString(16));
  }
  return result.join('');
}

function decodeString(s) {
  s = s.split('%');
  result = [];

  for (var i=0, iLen=s.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    result.push(String.fromCharCode(parseInt(s[i], 16)));
  }
  return result.join('');
}

alert(encodeString(s)); // %2d%20%5f%20%2e%20%21%20%7e%20%2a%20%27%20%28%20%29
```

The first wasn't decoding properly in IE 8, I didn't have time to fix it and don't have IE available right now. You may need to feature test to see which radix to use for decoding.

Answer (score 0):

The `encodeURIComponent` method should only be used on "pieces" (**components**) of the URL.  It's for putting together the query string or the path when you're constructing the URL from user-supplied or computed fragments.

There really can't be a general "encode my URL properly" method, because it can't tell what parts of the URL you do and don't want to encode. Instead, use `encodeURIComponent()` on the pieces of the URL that you're putting together *before* you add them to the final string.